# Uninstall backtrack 5 dual booted with Ubuntu

Tags: installation, uninstall, backtrack

Some days ago I installed BackTrack over my Ubuntu installation. I was having some problems in the bootloader of BackTrack. So I set default bootloader to that of Ubuntu. I didn't remember the command that I typed.
so now the default bootloader is of Ubuntu and I want to completely remove BackTrack. how to do that ?
If I just delete the installation files of backtrack from ubuntu then it'll still be there in the bootloader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the files of backtrack and type `sudo update-grub` in the terminal of Ubuntu.